# Refresh button on a website

Tags: website-design, usability, gui-design, web

Is it useful/sensible to display a 'Refresh' button on a website's page (simple page, not dialog!), like the picture below?

[image]

First I thought it's a good idea, but know I start to think it's not so good, because the users should (?) know how to refresh their browser-pages (both desktop and mobile).

Or is it better to provide them more and more buttons to perform actions like a 'normal' application?

In this case the 'Refresh' button reloads the full page and not just some part of it.

Comment: I think it depends on the use-case in question and to be honest I couldn't come up with a use-case that justifies an additional 'refresh' button. Your example is IMHO a horrible piece of UI where I strongly believe that the session should have silently recovered itself and the application should have continued working.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, unfortunately the current scenario is more complex than just simply recover the session silently :/

Comment: Yes I understand that, I was just saying that I couldn't come up with a use-case that justifies another `refresh` button, and the example that you give is in my opinion not justified either because technically that screen shouldn't exist. Perhaps your use-case in fact justifies a second `refresh` button. So that's why I say "it depends on the use-case". Can you describe your use-case a little better?

Comment: @Csabi On my desktop, I can just hit the Refresh button or press F5 to refresh the page. On my **phone**, I have to tap or swipe to open the menu, then tap Refresh to actually refresh the page. Adding a button makes it easier to refresh the page.

Comment: Unrelated, but I would consider minor grammatical changes to the error message. You do not need any commas. Consider this message: "Your session has timed out. Please click the "Refresh" button to reload the page."

Comment: @Andrew: thx a lot for the grammatical change proposal, I agree they are almost as important as a properly functioning logic.

Comment: @Bazzz: this page is embedded inside another hosting site via an IFRAME. The embedded site requires single-sign-on tokens in order to be accessed, therefore if the token is invalid/timesout/etc this page is displayed. It might happen that the hosting site (which contains the IFRAME and provides the SSO token) is buggy, and always provide wrong SSO tokens for this site. In this case if this page wouldn't exist and we would reload/refresh the whole window/tab everytime the child-site would receive a wrong SSO token which would result an endless refresh-loop. This is what I'd like to avoid.

Comment: @Bazzz part2: also, the child page (which this screenshot is about) does not really know about the hosting site/pag, and when your session times out and you perform an action, you get an error. Refreshing the full tab/window is required because of a new SSO token, but we can't redirect the user to the same subpage where s/he was because we have no control over how the hosting page's sets the IFRAME's source (which points to the child-website). I hope you understand :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Yes**, include the refresh button.

It is likely that the action of refreshing the page is the most likely scenario once this screen has been triggered. Even though the user may very likely know how to refresh the page, most users will have to think for a second before hitting the Refresh button (or F5).

You can justify including the refresh button with these [heuristics](http://www.nngroup.com/articles/ten-usability-heuristics/):

1. **Recognition rather than recall** - You are making the action of refresh visible instead of requiring the user to think about how to perform the action.
2. **Flexibility and efficiency of use** - Even for advanced users, having the refresh button may speed them up.
3. **Help users recognize, diagnose, and recover from errors** - The error message paired with the button helps the user understand what happened and log back in.

Comment: I agree all of your 3 points, Andrew. Thx!

Answer (score 2):

1. I'm a bit concerned about the refresh button appearing on a pop-up with no cancel/(x) button; What if the user entered input in the current page? - Would it be lost?
2. Optional refresh notices like on the top of the main page this site is nice - doesn't force the users to refresh, but alerts them to the need to refresh. Users can always use the built in browser's refresh button/shortcuts or click on the notice.

Comment: Danny, this is not a dialog, it's a simple page, maybe I didn't elaborate it properly. The page contains only that what's on the screenshot.

Comment: @Csabi There is no screenshot in the question other than that of the pop up.

Answer (score 0):

I have always been told never to assume your user can do something and make the application as simple and easy to use for the user. I definitely think in the case of the image above when a session times out a refresh button is offered. If there is a high possibility the user may need to refresh the page i would offer the button.